# Use of cassandra-lucene-index on high cardinality columns

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, cassandra, lucene, cassandra-lucene-index

I have use case which requires choosing either [Stratio cassandra-lucene-index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) or [Elastic Search](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) on Cassandra. I am more aligned towards the **Stratio implementation** as it doesn't require creating/managing ES clusters. However, the below scenario puts the solution implementation in difficult situation.

**Cassandra lucene Index** is created on high cardinality column e.g. **colA** in a key space **Test** (Keyspace has more than 10,000 unique records for colA) and following query is executed using Cassandra-lucene-index.

```
select * from Test where colA like “1%”
```

Now, the above query will require hitting all the nodes in the Cassandra cluster as the Cassandra Lucene indexes are local indexes.

So, *Will the query performance in such a scenario scale well with **Cassandra-lucene-index** compared to results returned from **ElasticSearch** Cluster with data feed from Cassandra as data in the Keyspace increases?*

Tools version:
Cassandra 3.10, Stratio cassandra-lucene-index 3.10

Comment: ElasticSearch and Solr are build for this type of job.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It will be great if more light can be shed on the topic.